# Hebrew text, some letters are changed incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, hebrew

I have a aproblem in azure devops ,
When resolving conflicts in a pull request  with a file that contains
Hebrew text, some letters are changed incorrectly.
for example , the letter א change to by letter ם
what I can do ?
thank and have a nice day :)

I changed the setting in the vs to UTF-8
but it's not help me ..

Answer (score 1):

I did not reproduce your issue in VS. However, I encountered the problem of incorrectly parsing Hebrew text in Azure DevOps pull request.
[image]

Only the Hebrew text in the text editing bar is parsed incorrectly. If you have the same issue, I suggest you [report it to the publisher of this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&ssr=false#qna). I noticed that there are already some users report issues related to Hebrew text, for example [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&ssr=false#qna:%7E:text=I%20have%20issue%20with%20HEBREW%20%D7%90%20TO%20%D7%9D%20change). As a workaround, it is recommended that you edit conflicting files directly in the repo.

If I misunderstand or you have this issue in VS, please share the specific steps and screenshots to help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: You understood correctly, several have already asked MICROSOFT for a solution to this
But we didn't get an answer
I thought maybe someone has an idea how to fix this as a workaround

Comment: This extension is developed by Microsoft DevLabs. At present, it seems to be an issue with the extension itself. I tried to find other extensions with similar functions in the marketplace, but I couldn't find them. I found that Hebrew text is not parsed incorrectly if copied from the windows above to the edit window below. I have helped you report this issue to the developer again. You can also report this issue. Hope the developers can understand the impact and fix it.